# How to use 5 columns as date in matplotlib?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have data that has first 6 columns as date and the last column is the value:

```
2013 03 17 00 00 00.000000 -3.140000

2013 03 17 00 00 30.000000 -2.140000
```

the data points are every 30 second. I would like to use column 0,1,2,3,5 as x value time and plot it versus the last column.

```
omnibz = np.loadtxt('data')

bz_plt = plt.plot(omni[:,5],omnibz[:,6],linewidth=1.1)
```

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: What are the dtypes for each column?

Comment: `0,1,2,3,5` that's 5 columns, not 4 as in the tittle.

Comment: It is ASCII file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work (but drops the decimal second):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = np.array([[2013,3,17,0,0,0.000000,
-3.140000],[2016,3,17,0,0,30.000000,-2.140000]])
d_time = pd.to_datetime(((d[:,0:1]*10000000000)+(d[:,1:2]*100000000)+(d[:,2:3]*1000000)+(d[:,3:4]*10000)+(d[:,4:5]*100)+np.round(d[:,5:6])).squeeze().astype(int),format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
plt.plot(d_time,d[:,6:7])
```